# Beamer figures shifting slide by slide

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to update a figure over several slides. I have four pictures (all the exact same width and height). I want to display the first image on the first slide, the second image on the second slide, and so on.

I've tried `\includegraphics<n>` for this purpose, but as I progress through the slides, the image shifts a bit to the right on each slide.

Is there a way to make everything stick in one place?

Minimal "working" example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=1610]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.7]{first.png}
        \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.7]{second.png}
        \includegraphics<3>[scale=0.7]{third.png}
        \includegraphics<4>[scale=0.7]{fourth.png}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `%` at the end of the lines containing `\includegraphics`, you're adding spaces there.

Comment: Ah, that would do it! The shifting is gone now. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer already loads this for you